# How to implement a customized principal builder in Kafka and use it for authorization using ACLs?

Tags: apache-kafka

I've enabled SSL authentication for all the communications between client and broker as well as inter-broker as per [this documentation.](http://docs.confluent.io/3.1.1/kafka/ssl.html) 
For using the authorization using ACLs, it has been mentioned in the documentation that the default principal name when using SSL authentication, the default SSL username will be of the form `CN=writeuser,OU=Unknown,O=Unknown,L=Unknown,ST=Unknown,C=Unknown` and to modify this we need to set a `principal.builder.class=CustomizedPrincipalBuilderClass`. 
I would like to get help on how to implement a new PrincipalBuilderClass and use that class to provide the SSL username as `CN+OU`. Any article showing a sample implementation of the above also works.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: 0
down vote
you ever get this sorted?

Trying to do the same thing now.

Cheers, Ben

Answer (score 0):

For custom PrincipalBuilder, you need to implement `KafkaPrincipalBuilder` class. In that class, you need to implement the `build` method which basically returns a `KafkaPrincipal` instance.

For a sample implementation, you can follow this: https://github.com/kafka-security/oauth/blob/master/kafka-oauth/src/main/java/com/bfm/kafka/security/oauthbearer/CustomPrincipalBuilder.java

I am copying an excerpt from the code in case it gets removed/moved in future,

```
public class CustomPrincipalBuilder implements KafkaPrincipalBuilder {
    @Override
    public CustomPrincipal build(AuthenticationContext authenticationContext) throws KafkaException{
        try {
            CustomPrincipal customPrincipal;

            if (authenticationContext instanceof SaslAuthenticationContext) {
                SaslAuthenticationContext context = (SaslAuthenticationContext) authenticationContext;
                OAuthBearerTokenJwt token = (OAuthBearerTokenJwt) context.server()
                        .getNegotiatedProperty("OAUTHBEARER.token");

                customPrincipal = new CustomPrincipal("User", token.principalName());
                customPrincipal.setOauthBearerTokenJwt(token);

                return customPrincipal;
            } else {
                throw new KafkaException("Failed to build CustomPrincipal. SaslAuthenticationContext is required.");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new KafkaException("Failed to build CustomPrincipal due to: ", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

The above exmaple uses `SASL OAUTHBEARER` for authentication/authorization purposes. But you can use any mechanism you want.

Comment: must implement also KafkaPrincipalSerde now